# KeyNavigation in SpinBox not working in qml

Tags: qt, qml

I'm using in my code `KeyNavigation.tab` property to make navigation workable in qml.

But the control `SpinBox`is not working with it. for example if i have a control between it and the element i want it to navigate it wont respect the rule.

I'm going to illustrate with a real example.

`main.cpp`

```
#include <QGuiApplication>
#include <QQmlApplicationEngine>

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    QCoreApplication::setAttribute(Qt::AA_EnableHighDpiScaling);

    QGuiApplication app(argc, argv);

    QQmlApplicationEngine engine;
    engine.load(QUrl(QStringLiteral("qrc:/main.qml")));
    if (engine.rootObjects().isEmpty())
        return -1;

    return app.exec();
}
```

and

`main.qml`

```
import QtQuick 2.9
import QtQuick.Controls 1.4
import QtQuick.Controls 2.0

ApplicationWindow {
    id: window
    title: "Stack"
    visible: true
    height: 200
    width: 400
    Item {
        id: page
        anchors.fill: parent
        width:parent.width
        height: parent.height
        ScrollView {
            id:scrollView
            anchors.fill:parent
            Column{
                width:parent.width
                spacing:10
                TextField {
                    id:textField
                    KeyNavigation.tab: spinBox1
                    implicitHeight: 30
                    font.bold: true
                }
                SpinBox {
                    id: spinBox1
                    KeyNavigation.tab: spinBox2
                    width: 100
                    height: 30
                    editable: true
                }
                ComboBox {
                    id:comboBox
                    //KeyNavigation.tab: spinBox2
                    anchors.topMargin: 10
                    textRole: "text"
                }
                SpinBox {
                    id: spinBox2
                    KeyNavigation.tab: textField
                    width: 100
                    height: 30
                    editable: true
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Here `spinBox1` wont jump to `spinBox2` if we use tab.

This was tested on a windows 10 OS

The version of Qt used is 5.11.1

Comment: I've tested it in Qt 5.12.1 on Linux and it works correctly

Comment: Maybe it is related with windows 10 then, it's where i tested.

Comment: Are you using the latest version of Qt? if so, I think it is a bug so it is recommended that you report it.

Comment: @yellanesc i'm using Qt Creator 4.8.1

Comment: @Nmaster88 I'm not asking you the version of Qt Creator, that's irrelevant. I'm asking you the version of Qt.

Comment: @yellanesc sry, it's version 5.11.1, i'm using this one to be in sync with my team.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For some reason, the QQuickKeyNavigationAttached::keyPressed() is not called if the attached property is set on the SpinBox itself instead of its TextInput. So, using the attached property on the contentItem is a workaround:

```
    SpinBox {
        Component.onCompleted: contentItem.KeyNavigation.tab = spinBox
    }
```